# Python, how to get number of unique ids per file and store filename and unique ids for each file in csv file?

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

I am working on a project to count the unique commenters in a chat and store the file name and number of commenters of that chat in a csv for each file. However, the code I have now is opening all of the documents and counting all the commenters across the multiple files. So, instead of getting the individual unique commenters per file, it is counting all the commenters across the multiple files. There are 10 unique commenters across all the files, however, I need to be able to see the number of unique commenters for each file and store that data in the csv file(see Desired Output for csv file picture). I feel like I am very close but I am stuck. Can anyone help with this issue or suggest other methods in doing this?

```
import os, sys, json
from collections import Counter
import csv
filename=""
filepath = ""
jsondata = ""
dictjson = ""
commenterid = []
FName = []
UList = []
TextFiles = []
UCommenter = 0


def get_FilePathList():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/ammcc/Desktop/"):
        for file in files:
            ##Find File with specific ending
            if file.endswith("chatinfo.txt"):
                path = "/Users/ammcc/Desktop/"
                ##Get the File Path of the file
                filepath = os.path.join(path,file)
                ##Get the Filename of the file ending in chatinfo.txt
                head, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
                ##Append all Filepaths of files ending in chatinfo.txt to TextFiles array/list
                TextFiles.append(filepath)
                ##Append all Filenames of files ending in chatinfo.txt to FName array/list
                FName.append(filename)

def open_FilePath():
     for x in TextFiles:
            ##Open each filepath in TextFiles one by one
            open_file = open(x)
            ##Read that file line by line
            for line in open_file:
                    ##Parse the Json of the file into jsondata
                    jsondata = json.loads(line)
                    ##Line not needed but, Parse the Json of the file into dictjson as Dictionary
                    dictjson = json.dumps(jsondata)

                    ## if the field commenter is found in jsondata
                    if "commenter" in jsondata:
                                    ##Then, append the field  ["commenter"]["_id"] **(nested value in the json)** into list commenterid
                                    commenterid.append(jsondata["commenter"]["_id"])
                                    ##Get and count the unique ids for the commenter
                                    Ucommenter = (len(set(commenterid)))
                                    ##Appended that unique count in UList
                                    UList.append(Ucommenter)


                                    ## create or append to the Commenter.csv file
                                    with open('Commenter.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
                                            filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                                            ##Write the individual filename and the unique commenters for that file
                                            filewriter.writerow([filename, Ucommenter])
            commenterid.clear()

                                            ##Issue: Not counting the commenters for each file and storing the filename and its specific number of commneters in csv.
                                            ##the cvs is being created but the rows in the csv is not generating correctly.

##Call the functions                                                     
get_FilePathList()
open_FilePath()
```

Current Output in csv file

[image]

Desired Output for csv file

[image]

Output after suggestion

[image]

Output and code after Nemanja Radojković solution:

**Correct output format, but still not counting the unique commenters per file.

[image]

```
import json, os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
TextFiles = []
FName = []
csv_rows = []
commenterid = []
unique_id = []
NC = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/ammcc/Desktop/"):
 for file in files:
     if file.endswith("chatinfo.txt"):
         path = "/Users/ammcc/Desktop/"
         filepath = os.path.join(path,file)
         head, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
         TextFiles.append(filepath)
         FName.append(filename)

         n_commenters = 0
         with open(filepath) as open_file:
             for line in open_file:
                 jsondata = json.loads(line)
                 if "commenter" in jsondata:
                     commenterid.append(jsondata["commenter"]["_id"])

                     list_set = set(commenterid)
                     unique_list = (list(list_set))

                 for x in list_set:
                     n_commenters += 1

                     commenterid.clear()
             csv_rows.append([filename, n_commenters])
df = pd.DataFrame(csv_rows, columns=['FileName', 'Unique_Commenters'])
df.to_csv('CommeterID.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: First (and probably the main) issue I see is that you're not resetting the `commenterid` list before entering each new file -- as far as I can see you're only adding elements to it.

Comment: You are suggesting clearing the commenterid with commenterid.clear()? And would i put that snippet after the creation of csv file or before?

Comment: I have changed the code and added the commenterid.clear. Please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json
import os
import pandas as pd

TextFiles = []
FName = []
csv_rows = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/ammcc/Desktop/"):

    for file in files:
        ##Find File with specific ending
        if file.endswith("chatinfo.txt"):

            path = "/Users/ammcc/Desktop/"
            ##Get the File Path of the file
            filepath = os.path.join(path,file)
            ##Get the Filename of the file ending in chatinfo.txt
            head, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
            ##Append all Filepaths of files ending in chatinfo.txt to TextFiles array/list
            TextFiles.append(filepath)
            ##Append all Filenames of files ending in chatinfo.txt to FName array/list
            FName.append(filename)

            n_commenters = 0

            with open(filepath) as open_file:
                ##Read that file line by line


                for line in open_file:
                        ##Parse the Json of the file into jsondata
                        jsondata = json.loads(line)

                        ## if the field commenter is found in jsondata
                        if "commenter" in jsondata:

                            n_commenters += 1

            csv_rows.append([filename, n_commenters])


df = pd.DataFrame(csv_rows, columns=['filename', 'n_commenters'])

df.to_csv('some_filename.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\ammcc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 1071, in get_terminal_size
    size = os.get_terminal_size(sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Comment: Also incrementing the value n_commenters will not allow me to pull out unique commenters for the file. It will increment whenever it sees the commenter field. What if the same user comments twice or multiple time? That user will be counted twice or how many ever times they commented. This will skew the numbers significantly. Is there a way to count them by their id and then increment that number?

Comment: Still working on getting the code to work. I believe I need to install pandas via pip and then import it.

Comment: Got the code to work. (had to install pip then install pandas.) However, as expected the unique commenters are not being counted. All the commenters per file are being counted without removing the duplicates. However, the csv format is perfect. I had to get the indent right but it finally went through. I will post the edits to the orignal question.